# How to get rid of System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll in project's build?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package

We have MVC 4 project in solution, now in VS 2015.
When solution built, there is System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll in the bin folder of the project.
It is copied there every time solution is built.
We need code that we deploy to be PCI compliant.
But System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll is Not compliant.

Project does Not use SQLServer Compact Edition.
Project uses SQL 2008.
Project has reference to EntityFramework package, but does Not use EntityFramework.
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll seem to be part of EntityFramework package.

I have removed reference to EntityFramework from References in project.
Then I have tried to UN-install EntityFramework with "UnInstall-Package EntityFramework" and "UnInstall-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.1.3"  in "Package Manager Console".

### Both times I got error:

UnInstall-Package : Unable to uninstall 'EntityFramework.5.0.0' because 'Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core.1.2.0' depends on it.
At line:1 char:1
+ UnInstall-Package EntityFramework
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Uninstall-Package], Exception

### + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UninstallPackageCommand

Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core  - is ASP.NET Universal Providers add provider support in ASP.NET 4 for all editions of SQL Server 2005 and later and to SQL Azure. If you use these providers to develop your application, the application will be ready for cloud environments like Azure.

Project does use SQL Server 2008 and soon we plan to deploy it to Azure environment.
So, looks like we can Not un-install "Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core".

QUESTION: Of course this dll probably can be removed every time before we deploy to QA or Prod environment, but is there any other solution to this issue? How to prevent System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll to be copied to bin folder during build?

Many thanks

Comment: Does this help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx

Comment: I guess one of you dependencies reference System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll, so remove that reference

Comment: ErikEJ - I Did found dependency : The error I've posted in my question Does tell what depends on EntityFramework package that has  System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll. And I Did explain why I think Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core can Not be removed. Do you have different opinion ? Thank you

Comment: Nick.McDermaid  - sorry, but link you gave me does not help. System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll is Not in the list of dependencies, as I specified in my Question:System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll seem to be part of EntityFramework paqckage.